# Adding email address to Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a beginner in PowerShell. I have 1500 service accounts in Active Directory which are missing email addresses; I want to update the SAME email addresses in all the accounts.

Example email address: `ecertprocess@abc.com`

Please help me writing this PowerShell code.

I have all accounts SamAccountName and DN details.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _update the SAME email addresses_? and update to what new email addresses? Are you trying to set email aliases (lowercase `smtp:`) or do you want the primary emailaddress changed (uppercase SMTP:) in ProxyAddresses attribute? Please supply examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find all the users who don't have a email address (You can change the SearchBase) and add email address of them.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "dc=test,dc=net" | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -eq ''} | ForEach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -EmailAddress "Email Address"}
```

If you have list of users in a csv like:

```
SamAccountName,
xxx,
yyy,
```

then:

```
Import-Csv "Filepath" -Header SamAccountName -Delimiter "," | ForEach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -EmailAddress "Email Address"}
```

Comment: It's worked and I have tried LDIF file update using regex method too..thank you for your time.